How to disambiguate overloaded (by parameters typed by templates) function call for std::bind?
Is there a straightforward way to bind a specific overloaded function from two which differ by parameters typed by templates?
I read dozens of similar topics here, but can't find a proper way to bind a specific solution for this particular case:
#include <functional>

template <typename T>  
struct range { T min = {}; T max = {}; };

float random(const range<float>&)
{
    return 0.0f;
}

int random(const range<int>&)
{
    return 0;
}

void change_random(auto changer)
{
}

int main()
{
    // Could not deduce template argument
    auto bound1 = std::bind(random, range<int>(1, 2));

    // syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ')'
    auto bound2 = std::bind(random<range<int>>, range<int>(1, 2));
        
    // Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
    auto bound3 = std::bind<float,decltype(random(range<float>(0.0f,0.0f)))>(random, range<int>(1, 2));

    // cannot convert argument 1 from 'overloaded-function' to '_Fx (__cdecl &&)'
    auto bound4 = std::bind<float, float(range<float>&)>(random, range<int>(1, 2));

    change_random(bound1);
}

Demo.
Can this be done without additional wrappers, templates of templates etc.? If not, what is the shortest way to do this and why my approaches haven't worked?

std::bind(static_cast<int(*)(const range<int>&)>(random), range<int>(1, 2));. But do yourself a favor, forget std::bind and use lambdas: auto bound1 = [](){ return random(range<int>(1, 2)); };

change_random(bound1); ain't gonna work with any bound1. The way change_random is declared, its T parameter is non-deducible (since it's not mentioned in any way in the argument list), and so needs to be explicitly spelled out in the call, e.g. change_random<int>(bound1). Though frankly, I don't understad what it's supposed to do, what role it plays in your example.

@IgorTandetnik, thank you for the solution! Works like a charm. I will come back with some questions on it (really, on "why my other attempts don't work"). Thanks for catching code typo in the definition of the change_random (I've updated the question) to keep it consistent. On the lambda, I love the approach. Do you recommend it because it is more readable or there are some other benefits and flexibility?

Lambdas mostly just work where std::bind just doesn't (as you've discovered). And yes, I find lambda syntax more readable (though that's a matter of taste, I suppose). std::bind with parameter placeholders is particularly atrocious, whereas lambda declares parameters in a natural way.

@DamirTenishev the std::bind was useful when lambdas would not capture by move, I guess that was pre-C++11. Also, bound objects can accept arbitrary number of arguments, the superfluous ones are just discarded. It might matter in more convoluted generic code.
